# Converting QByteArray to hex, bin and char

Tags: qt, c++17, qbytearray

I have been trying to convert QByteArray data into a hex, bin and char tabular representation, but I encounter problems when in the QByteArray there are escape sequences... for example if I have the QByTeArray which contains "Hello World" the space is not converted into Hex, but it remains a space... what do I do?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

         std::cout << "0x" << QString::number(0, 16).toStdString() << "\t";

         if (((i+1) % 8) == 0)
             std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

this is the code used for example to run through the QByteArray and transform it into a hex representation.

Btw, I am using QT creator to program in C++ and I'm a beginner

I tried converting the QByteArray into a QString containing the translation into ASCII of the data, so that then maybe with an if else explain the behaviour the program should have every it encounters a number from 00 to 32... but it requires massive effort. Isn't there a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you never use a `QByteArray` but instead output `0x0` for `n` iterations.

Assuming, you have some array containing "Hello World", your loop correctly outputs hex values iff you use `i` to access the array elements and `.length()` instead of `n`:

```cpp
const QByteArray data = "Hello World";
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
    
    std::cout << "0x" << QString::number(data[i], 16).toStdString() << "\t";
    
    if (((i+1) % 8) == 0)
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0x48    0x65    0x6c    0x6c    0x6f    0x20    0x57    0x6f    
0x72    0x6c    0x64
```

Answer (score 0):

The QByteArray class already has QByteArray::toHex() method.

```
QByteArray arr = "Hello world";    
std::cout << QString("0x" + arr.toHex(':')).replace(":", " 0x").toStdString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.